# Best way of concatenating one value of objects by comma separation? C#

Tags: c#, linq

I found a way to do this but I just wonder if there is actually a straight way to do it.

So I have list of Artist objects and I would like to print out all the artists name as one string with comma separated.

here is my code to achieve this

```
string.Join(",",Artists.Select(a => a.ArtistName).ToArray());
```

Or I should be using ToString method?

Comment: your code looks fine to me

Comment: your code looks fine to me buddy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From .NET framework version 4 onwards, this should be enough

```
string s = string.Join(",",Artists.Select(a => a.ArtistName));
```

Comment: From .NET framework version 4 onwards, but yes, preferable if it's there.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon what one means by "best".

Generally, the way you have it is best prior to .NET 4.0, while from 4.0 on the best way is to leave out the `.ToArray()` because from that version on there is a form of `Join` that takes an `IEnumerable<string>` and hence you don't need to spend time and memory creating an array.

Now, if we are working prior to .NET 4.0, we can create our own version of those added with that version:

```
public static class StringMore
{
//You might want to use conditional statements to mark this as obsolete in 4.0 or higher
  public static string Join(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values)
  {
    if (values == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    if (separator == null)
      separator = string.Empty;
    using (IEnumerator<string> en = values.GetEnumerator())
    {
      if (!en.MoveNext())
        return "";
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(en.Current);
      while(en.MoveNext())
      {
        stringBuilder.Append(separator);
        stringBuilder.Append(en.Current);
      }
      return sb.ToString();
    }
  }
  public static string Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)
  {
    if (values == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    if (separator == null)
      separator = string.Empty;
    using (IEnumerator<string> en = values.GetEnumerator())
    {
      if (!en.MoveNext())
        return "";
      T cur = en.Current;
      StringBuilder sb = cur == null ? new StringBuilder() : new StringBuilder(cur.ToString());
      while(en.MoveNext())
      {
        stringBuilder.Append(separator);
        cur = en.Current;
        if(cur != null)
          stringBuilder.Append(cur.ToString());
      }
      return sb.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could use `StringMore.Join(",",Artists.Select(a => a.ArtistName))` to get results in .NET 3.5 that are almost (not quite as we lack some caching of `StringBuilder`s that .NET does internally) as efficient as 4.0. Whether this is "better" or not depends on whether the performance gain is worth the extra work and extra complexity to bug-checking of adding more methods, which depends on how heavy the calls are in practice (how many elements) and how often they are hit.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is the correct way. You "could" override the ToString method of your object `Artists`, but string.Join is the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

separateor could be ","

```
public static string Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string separator)
{
    return items.Join(separator, i => i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You need to check that one, I think.

Comment: This just needs another thing, to override Artist.ToString() to return the ArtistName. Good answer though

Comment: Doesn't work or compile. You are calling IEnumerable<T>.Join which joins two collections.

Answer (score -1):

I'd prefer to create my own method here, in order to make my code "look better". So I would make an extension to the list of artists.

```
public static class ArtistListExtensions
{
    public static String unionNames(this List<Artist> artists, String seperator)
    {
        return string.Join(seperator, artists.Select(a => a.ArtistName));
    }
}
```

I would now simply use this extension as such:

```
artists.unionNames(", ");
```

Comment: The whole point of using Join is to avoid string concatenation and creating multiple temporary strings. Can't see what this offers over Join or why it looks better than the one-liner. It *will* cause a serious performance hit. Also, it's non-generic as it works only for List<Artist> collections

Comment: This results in code that is less clear (it's more obvious what the code in the question does than what `unionNames` does), unidiomatic (lower-case method name in .NET), very wasteful of time and memory (multiple string creations of increasing size), handles the fact that you don't want the separator at the beginning in a very clumsy and wasteful manner. It's hard to think how you could make this any worse and still give the correct final result.

Comment: My answer intends to point out the importance of an expression to make the final call easier to read and not how the extension does the job. I'll edit it to avoid any confusion. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: It's still hard-coded to a specific collection type, non-idiomatic (method name starts with lower case letter) and doesn't offer something over the equivalent String.Join one-liner